# How to read XML data from https address

Tags: c#

How can I read data from a `HTTPS` address?

When I am trying to get data from `http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml`, my code works fine but it fails when I try to access `https://live.af.centurylink.com/PRISMPOC/AFTelephonyRWS/restful/3032971029/call?token=082b96247aa6c2cce2007e9270eeabe1485988d17c3d832553cf562f0f6aef96&maximumnumberofrecords=10`

with error:

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

My code is:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest.Method = "GET";
webRequest.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mp0010484", "mp00com", "domain");
webRequest.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mp0010484", "mp00com", "domain");

webRequest.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;

using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(streamReader.ReadToEnd()));
        string xml = document.Root.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(xml);
    }
}
```

Comment: It means: you don't have the **permissions** to read from that URL - you might need to **register** or sign up for access to that URL

Comment: Are those real credentials for a publicly-accessible URL? If so, you probably don't want to share them.

Comment: Also you can try to open the URL in a browser first. It also does not open ;)

Comment: no they are not real.

Comment: @ZoolWay  i check it it is working fine in browser & showing data but when i try to access it through code not able to access

Comment: yew we can see data but not able o access through code but now i am able to access from code as well when i dont set contentType & uses my own inernet modem instead of company lan.